# Can the links in D3.js Sankey Diagrams be anything besides cubic bézier curves?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, flowchart, sankey-diagram

I am trying to make an energy flow diagram with D3.js using the [Sankey library](https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey). In every [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca9a0bb7ba204d12974bca90acc507c0) I have seen, the links between nodes look similar and curve continuously. My understanding is that the Sankey library code uses the D3 Shape library to draw a cubic bézier curve.

**I am wondering if there is any standard way to draw more complex connection links?**

Specifically, I would like the the connections to look like [these flow charts](https://flowcharts.llnl.gov/content/assets/images/charts/Energy/Energy_2016_United-States.png) created by [Lawrence Livermore National Lab](https://flowcharts.llnl.gov/commodities/energy) or [this diagram](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jouni_Paavola/publication/303306020/figure/fig7/AS:363006774005762@1463558967135/Figure-S3-Sankey-diagram-on-global-grey-virtual-water-flows-Sankey-diagram-for-virtual.png) from [an academic article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jiec.12454/full). Both of these have some kind of "buffer" before the curve, and the diagonal sections appear parallel (or somewhat parallel) to each other. For my situation I'd prefer if all the diagonal sections were parallel at 45 degree angles with variably sized buffer zones.

Does anyone have any ideas on how could this be done? I am new to D3.js and would appreciate any help or direction you have!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the "standard" ways are the pre-defined [link functions](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#links) in D3... but we can replace those with **any** function that returns a new [path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) definition string. The input to the function is the link object, which has the source and target x/y coordinates. So a simple straight line "path" between the two could be implemented like this:

```
function straightLine(d, i) {
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y +
          " L" + d.target.y + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

which you would use to set the "d" attribute on your svg `<path>` elements, like so:

```
svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(mydata)
    .attr("d", straightLine);
```

For your particular case, building a path with horizontal start/end sections and 45° angled middle section, we use the start/end points to calculate the intermediate junction points -- for example:

```
function angledLine(d, i) {
    var dh = d.target.x - d.source.x; // horizontal distance
    var dv = d.target.y - d.source.y; // vertical distance
    var a1 = d.source.x + (dy - dx)/2; // 1st angle point x
    var a2 = d.target.x - (dy - dx)/2; // 2nd angle point x

    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y +
          " L" + a1 + "," + d.source.y + 
          " L" + a2 + "," + d.target.y + 
          " L" + d.target.y + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

The first arg `d` is the link object. For clarity, I'm generating a rather verbose path string (connected lines with absolute coordinates). This works fine, but can be simplified by using the "H" and "V" commands to move horizontally/vertically (or the lower-case versions to move relative distances). You can also string x,y pairs together without the "L" command, if you want to shorten the path string (less data, but possibly less readable, too).

> Note: this implementation assumes that the horizontal distance is > the vertical distance. I'll leave it up to the OP to determine how to modify the path  for the other case (change the angle? add a vertical line in the middle of the angle? add vertical sections to each end?)
>   A well crafted link generator will have to account for top-bottom vs. left-right layouts, as well as a target on the other side of the source (negative distances). But this should help get you started...

The second arg `i` is the index of the link in the data array. Although it's not used in this example, it could be used to push the angled section left or right, to help avoid some overlaps in parallel paths. YMMV